# Bad Pickle of FormData (error found)

Tags: javascript, aptana

I'm in a web class that is taking me through JavaScript, HTTP, and CSS. While I was using the Aptana software, I have had spotty use. I can load a program about 50% of the time correctly, but most of my time is spent getting the current version to run instead of an older version of the same file(or that is my guess).

I get the error :

> [7272:7748:0108/183306:ERROR:form_data.cc(108)] Bad pickle of
>   FormData, no version present

multiple times as I try to test code. I am currently using Internet Explorer and Google Chrome to test the codes I write. I'm sorry, but I do not know how relevant this would be to others as I am just beginning to learn coding.

As far as I can tell, this is a bug that is mainly with Google Chrome. I have downloaded Firefox as well as re-downloaded the Aptana software and it works well.

Comment: we're going to need more information, since "pickles" have nothing to do with javascript. This sounds like a problem with Aptana, not JavaScript; what are you doing that causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

I just started having the same problem. I have been using Aptana for about 6 months. When I run my application in Chrome, just recently I'm getting the same error.

More recently, I have added an "enhancedgrid" to my application. When I was just giving feedback of the results to a paragraph message, it worked fine. I've recently been trying to get the results to go into the grid. Now, after I enter a value into an input field, it doesn't do anything, not even to my paragraph message. the onclick seems to have stopped working and I'm getting these bad pickles.

I'm in a pickle...

Answer (score 0):

This message is not related to Aptana, and from what i can tell is mostly benign.

Chrome outputs a lot of debug messages to console, most of it is not any cause for concern.

I see this message often on my Mac, but I've yet to correlate it to any ill effects